# Union of Deterministic Context Free Language and Regular Language results?

Tags: union, regular-language, context-free-language

Given L1 is Deterministic context free languages & L2 is Regular language. 
 L1 U L2 results DCFL or regular?

please give some examples with the context

Comment: hint: a simple example `a^nb^c^n` U `x^ny^x^n`, now what is it??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Neither of those languages are regular, though, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @templatetypedef  yes, you are correct,  my comment is not useful :( to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting language must be a DCFL. Intuitively, you could check if a string is in the union of a DCFL and a regular language by getting a DPDA for the DCFL, a DFA for the regular language, then running the two in parallel and seeing if either accept. You can simulate that process by using a variation of the product construction that shows that the regular languages are closed under union: build a DPDA with one state for each combination of a DFA state and a DPDA state, then structure the transitions so that they simulate following a transition from the DPDA and the DFA in parallel. You only need one stack for this, so the construction should work just fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

l2=sigma* and L1=a^nb^n
l1 is dcfl and l2 is regular.but L1 union l2=l1 is dcfl but not regular

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the union of those two languages Sigma*, which is indeed regular?